# The facebook login window pops up and immediately closes for all accouts except mine

Tags: flutter, facebook-login

using the flutter_facebook_login pacakage and https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-facebook-login-77fcd187242 link, facebook login window appears but closes immediately. 
This problem exists when i try my app using other facebook accounts, but it works for my own facebook id.

The problem most probably lies with the user access token, how can i allow multiple users to access the login features when using the app?

The error that shows is :

```
W/ActivityThread(30135): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@6ccdd3
I/Timeline(30135): Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:15389566 intent:Intent { cmp=com.facebook.katana/.ProxyAuth (has extras) }
```

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';
import 'package:flutter_signin_button/flutter_signin_button.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(FacebookLoginPage());
}

class FacebookLoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FacebookLoginPageState createState() => _FacebookLoginPageState();
}

class _FacebookLoginPageState extends State<FacebookLoginPage> {
  bool isLoggedIn = false;
  var profileData;

  var facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();

  void onLoginStatusChanged(bool isLoggedIn, {profileData}) {
    setState(() {
      this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
      this.profileData = profileData;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Facebook Login"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.exit_to_app,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () => facebookLogin.isLoggedIn
                  .then((isLoggedIn) => isLoggedIn ? _logout() : {}),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: isLoggedIn
                ? _displayUserData(profileData)
                : _displayLoginButton(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void initiateFacebookLogin() async {
    var facebookLoginResult =
        await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);

    switch (facebookLoginResult.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        onLoginStatusChanged(false);
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        onLoginStatusChanged(false);
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        var graphResponse = await http.get(
            'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,picture.height(200)&access_token=${facebookLoginResult.accessToken.token}');

        var profile = json.decode(graphResponse.body);
        print(profile.toString());

        onLoginStatusChanged(true, profileData: profile);
        break;
    }
  }

  _displayUserData(profileData) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 200.0,
          width: 200.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              image: NetworkImage(
                profileData['picture']['data']['url'],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 28.0),
        Text(
          "Logged in as: ${profileData['name']}",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  _displayLoginButton() {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      child: SignInButton(
        Buttons.Facebook,
        // mini: true,
        // width: 200.0,
        text: "Sign in with Facebook",
        onPressed: () {
          initiateFacebookLogin();
        },
      ),
    );
    // return RaisedButton(
    //   child: Text("Login with Facebook"),
    //   onPressed: () => initiateFacebookLogin(),
    // );
  }

  _logout() async {
    await facebookLogin.logOut();
    onLoginStatusChanged(false);
    print("Logged out");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
It was with the development status of the application in the facebook developer console. 
You have to make the app public in order for other users to log in.

Comment: @JayMungara No. But be careful with the app hash keys. they can generate errors.

Comment: @ Rojan  Where is the option to make the app public in facebook developer console?